# Failed to listen on prefix 'http://IPAddress:Port/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine

Tags: c#, tcp, listener, tcpclient, httplistener

The ACOPTesterListener method works great the first time a message received on listener URI, but fails with a data exception error on the subsequent execution of the GetContext with the following message: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://IPAddress:Port/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.

I start the background http listener thread:

```
#region "Start Http Listener Thread"
ACOPTesterListenerCS acoptesterlistenercs = new ACOPTesterListenerCS();
Thread HttpListenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(acoptesterlistenercs.ACOPTesterListener));
HttpListenerThread.IsBackground = true;
HttpListenerThread.Start();
PropertiesCS.p_ACOPTesterListenerThreadFlag = true;
#endregion
```

Here is the listener class:

```
#region "ACOPTesterListener"
public void ACOPTesterListener()
{
    try
    {  
        #region "Continue to listen until Middleware is closed"
        while (PropertiesCS.p_ACOPTesterListenerThreadFlag)
        {
         #region "Waits for request"
         HttpListenerContext webcontext = PropertiesCS.p_ACOPTesterListener.GetContext();
         HttpListenerRequest webrequest = webcontext.Request;
         #endregion

         #region "Read middleware test request response message"
         Stream RequestMsg = webrequest.InputStream;
         StreamReader webstreamreader = new StreamReader(RequestMsg);
         string RequestBody = webstreamreader.ReadToEnd();
         string contenttype = webrequest.ContentType;
         #endregion
        }
        #endregion
        PropertiesCS.p_ACOPTesterListener.Stop();
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PropertiesCS.p_Message = "ACOPTesterListener - Error message: " + ex.Message;
        return;
    }
}
#endregion
```

I set a break point on the ACOPTesterListener method try catch, then ran the netstat -ano command.

- Before the first listener event occurs the following netstat info was displayed:

  - TCP 10.73.10.121:86 0.0.0.0 Listening 4
- After the first listener event the following netstat info was displayed:

  - TCP 10.73.10.121:86 0.0.0.0 Listening 4
  - TCP 10.73.10.121:86 10.73.10.121:51365 Established 4

The listing event works, but when the ACOPTesterListener method attempts to do the next GetContext the method exceptions out with the "Fails to Listen" error. 
Any assistance resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: You either need to use one request or close the connection in each for loop.  Solution 1) Move the HttpListenerRequest webrequest = webcontext.Request; before the while loop 2) Put code inside the while loop in a using statement so the request is disposed after each loop.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including your wrapper class, without all the boilerplate. You can only listen for HTTP calls using one HttpListener on a given endpoint at a time.

Comment: JDweng - Can you share with me some sample of how to code up the using statement.  I'm a bit stuck on this one.  Or point me in the direction of a good code example.  The disposing of the request is tripping me up.  Thanks

Comment: CodeCaster - I took your advise and worked up a bear bones http host and client solution.  Both have listeners and message successfully back and forth repeatedly.  Tomorrow I have to spin up another thread on the host to message with the ACOP controller.  I need to get the rundown message info so that the host can message it back to the client.  Repeatedly is the key thing, it works the first time.